# Weird pdfLaTeX+babel+color bug, Missing = inserted for \ifnum

Tags: pdftex

I let the MWE speak for itself.

```
\documentclass{minimal}
% remove babel and it works
% remove one language and it works
% reorder the languages and it works
\usepackage[italian,spanish,UKenglish]{babel}
% remove the color package and it works
\usepackage{color}
\begin{document}
hi
\end{document}
```

which outputs

> ```
> This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (TeX Live 2013/Debian)
> ```
>
> ...
>
> ```
> (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/supp-pdf.mkii
> [Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
> ! Missing = inserted for \ifnum.
> <to be read again> 
>                    \let 
> l.400 \newcount\nofMPsegments
> ```

Comment: Add `\usepackage{etex}` to allow for more count register.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer That works. But why should a certain language order use more registers than the same languages in another order? I can even add many more languages and packages without any problems, but this particular language order 'crashes'.

Comment: italian.ldf actually loads etoolbox (and so etex), but it is often important to load it early enough. I didn't really check what exactly break here. (The next latex version will make it unnecessary to load etex).

Comment: I still don't understand why it should be a register limit problem. Why should `[italian,spanish,UKenglish]` need more memory than `[italian,UKenglish,spanish]` or `[danish,french,ngerman,spanish,italian,UKenglish]`?

Comment: The problem is not the number of registers but (probably) when exactly etex enters the game. etex changes the allocation system, and when it does it at the wrong moment you can get problems. But this is speculation, I didn't really check.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a complement to [egreg's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/233276/4686)

The source of the problem is that `etoolbox` hence `etex` will be loaded at a time where `<` is active. This is not completely catastrophic though, because even with `<` active, it might well expand to a catcode 12 `<` hence could work ok in `\ifnum` tests. However when package `color` is loaded and used with driver `pdftex` it then loads support file `supp-pdf.mkii` for MPS to PDF conversion. This file temporarily modifies the definition of `\protect`. And the active `<` then gives something unacceptable to `\ifnum`.

With only `\usepackage[italian,spanish]{babel}` and without `color` there is thus no error.

For some reason `spanish.ldf` <strike>temporarily makes</strike> makes `<` and `>` active <strike>during the time it is loaded by `babel`</strike> at the very end of `spanish.ldf`. This activity is cancelled for the rest of the preamble until `\AtBeginDocument` by code executed immediately after `babel.sty` is loaded. In the order `\usepackage[spanish, italian]{babel}` the loading of `etoolbox` which was demanded by `italian.ldf` at the end of package Babel is thus executed *after* the code, also at end of package Babel, which resets to unactive the catcodes of the activated characters by spanish (edit: activated at the very end of `spanish.ldf` itself).

In the order of `\usepackage[italian,spanish]{babel}` the end of package Babel demands of `italian` (which include the loading of package `etoolbox` hence also of package `etex`) are executed *before* those of `spanish`. As a result this is done at a time where `<` is active. Hence `etex` definition of `\alloc@` is done with an active `<`. This is recipe for disaster although as seen above in some circumstances it may remain hidden, becasue the active `<` still will extend to a catcode 12 `<`.

I do not know enough the innards of Babel, but it appears to me that `spanish.ldf` <strike>should not demand to Babel to reset the catcodes of `<` and `>` at the end of loading of `babel.sty` [snip] but do it him/herself at the end of `spanish.ldf`</strike>...
in fact I am not sure `spanish.ldf` makes any explicit demand of this type what I see is that

1. it demands to Babel to activate `<` and `>`,
2. then it immediately resets the catcodes to `12`,
3. then at the very last command of `spanish.ldf` one sees it re-activates `<` and `>`.

Babel by default I think resets to `12` the catcodes for the rest of the preamble when the activation was done properly (I do not investigate more, but I tested it in the case of `spanish` by itself).

Thus, I recommend this issue should be raised to the `spanish.ldf` and `babel.sty` maintainers. In fact, it would seem that the `\csname activatequoting\endcsname` at the end of `spanish.ldf` might be a bug (perhaps should be from what I understand only `\let\es@quoting\activatequoting` but not do `\shorthandon{<>}` ?), as anyhow Babel resets for the rest of the preamble the catcodes to `12`.

Comment: Yes, it was a bug. Fixed.

Comment: @JavierBezos apologies for not having made a legit bug report...

Answer (score 5):

The problem is in the fact that `babel-spanish`, by default, makes `<` as a shorthand character and with certain combinations of languages this ends with this strange error that is surely due to this fact. The complete error message if one enables more `\errorcontextlines` is

```
! Missing = inserted for \ifnum.
<to be read again> 
                   \let 
\protect ->\let 
                \protect \@@mpstopdf@@protect \let \unprotect \@@mpstopdf@@u...

\active@prefix ...tect \noexpand #1\else \protect 
                                                  #1\fi \expandafter \@gobbl...

<->\active@prefix <
                   \normal@char< 
\alloc@ #1#2#3#4#5->\ifnum \count 1#1<
                                      #4\allocationnumber \count 1#1 \global...
l.400 \newcount\nofMPsegments
```

It's not very clear why loading `italian` before `spanish` produces the error and it's quite unclear why `\usepackage[italian,spanish]{babel}` *doesn't* stop.

However, calling the languages in a different order “fixes” the issue:

```
\usepackage[spanish,italian,UKenglish]{babel}
```

Alternatively, load `etex` just after the `\documentclass` lines.

What happens is that `etoolbox` is loaded at the wrong time, but there doesn't seem a better place for calling it from `italian.ldf` (apart not loading it in the first place).