# XeLaTeX: incomplete \iffalse with pdfpages and spanish babel

Tags: xetex, babel, pdfpages

The following code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\begin{document}
\includepdf[landscape]{example-image-16x9.pdf}
\end{document}
```

when compiled with `XeLaTeX`, produces

```
! Incomplete \iffalse; all text was ignored after line 5
```

The conflicting options are `landscape` on `\includepdf` and `spanish` language. Without `landscape` it compiles, and without `babel` or with `english` also compiles good.

The error only appears with `XeLaTeX`. Neither `pdfLaTeX` nor `luaLaTeX` yields that error.

There is something to do?

Comment: I think that the recommended way is to use `polyglossia` instead of `babel` in xelatex and lualatex.... But I can't check now.

Comment: Hmmm... checked now, I have no error with xelatex on your snippet. Version-dependent? (mine is quite old, it's the stock Ubuntu 14.04, so around TeXLive 2012).

Comment: Works for me, too, with the latest release. Please, Emilio, could you say which versions of `pdfpages`, `babel` and `spanish` are used?

Comment: @JavierBezos on my system, the problem exists, it is even so severe that the log is cut before `\listfiles` can produce a result.... compiling with `babel` loaded second, I get `pdfpages.sty    2015/09/18 v0.5d`, `babel.sty    2016/01/08 3.9n`, `spanish.ldf 2016/01/15 v5.0o`. And `XeTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.99992 (TeX Live 2015) (preloaded format=xelatex 2016.1.20)`

Comment: @JavierBezos and @Rmano: Debian sid TeXLive 2015.20160117-1. `pdfpages` version v0.5d and `babel` 3.9n. Thanks!

Comment: After upgrading `pdfpages` I could reproduce the error, and jfbu is (almost) right in the answer below. I don't think loading a package when the document has started is a good idea, but if done catcodes should be sanitized (except if we want the catcodes as used in the document body, of course), as done in font encodings with `\nfss@catcodes`. Note the example fails even with the current version of `spanish`, with a bug fixed - catcodes are now activated at the right time, but `pdfpages` is loaded too late. I think you should contact the maintainer of `pdfpages`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can disable the pretty useless “quoting” feature of Spanish `babel`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[spanish,es-noquoting]{babel}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\begin{document}
\includepdf[landscape]{example-image-16x9.pdf}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

This is an issue with `<` and `>` being active at the wrong time. It appears at a time when the landscape option (and xetex driver for pdfpages) will try to do

```
\special {pdf: put @thispage <</Rotate #1>>}
```

I didn't try to disentangle completely the sequence of events (*but see update below*), but loading babel after pdfpages fixes the issue. I recall from another question I contributed to that spanish has some problems in its handling of active characters, but I need to find that link.

The link is https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/233355/4686  but the underlying mechanism is not the one at works here.

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage[spanish]{babel}% provokes problems with active <, >
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\begin{document}
%\tracingifs1
%\tracingmacros1
\includepdf[landscape]{example-image-16x9.pdf}
\end{document}
% Local Variables:
% TeX-engine: xetex
% End:
```

compiles fine (although perhaps the outcome has problems with margins).

### Update

One sees in package `pdfpages` that it does

```
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \let\AM@orig@landscape\landscape
  \let\AM@orig@endlandscape\endlandscape
  \RequirePackage{pdflscape}%
  \let\landscape\AM@orig@landscape
  \let\endlandscape\AM@orig@endlandscape
}
```

The important thing is thus that the `\RequirePackage{pdflscape}` is done at a very late time. If the user loads `babel` before `pdfpages` then `Babel` will have activated the shorthands at that time. And inside package `pdflscape` one finds

```
  \def\PLS@AtBeginShipout{%
    \global\setbox\AtBeginShipoutBox\vbox{%
      \special{pdf: put @thispage <</Rotate #1>>}%
      \box\AtBeginShipoutBox
    }%
```

where the `<` and `>` are active characters due to `Babel+spanish`. If I replace this by

```
  \def\PLS@AtBeginShipout{%
    \global\setbox\AtBeginShipoutBox\vbox{%
      \special{pdf: put @thispage \string<\string</Rotate #1\string>\string>}%
      \box\AtBeginShipoutBox
    }%
```

then your MWE compiles with no error, even with `babel` loaded before `pdfpages`. Moreover near the bottom of the file `pdflscape.sty` I see a use of `<, >` in an `\@whilenum` loop, here also `<` and `>` should better not be active, although here they do not cause problem because they only fetch the next token I believe to check for `<<` or `>>`.

It can not be said that `pdflscape` should sanitize the catcodes of `<` and `>`, as then zillions of packages should too.

Is it really necessary that `pdfpages` loads `pdflscape` during `\AtBeginDocument` hook ? perhaps an `\AtEndOfPackage` would be enough ?

Comment: Anyway, babel active characters are a PITA... I normally use http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/19394/38080, nowadays with utf8 almost universally spread I think they're do more harm than good. Also see http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/106325/38080

Comment: @Rmano Under `xelatex`, `spanish` could perhaps use the `\XeTeXintercharclass` mechanism rather than active characters. This is what `frenchb` does, hence no more any worries with active characters. However, there are some remaining fringe issues, it appears not be `100%` appropriate enough for insertion of the special spacing for French punctuation, as `frenchb` author told me. Possibly for things like `<<` and `>>` in Spanish, the `XeTeX` `\XeTeXintercharclass would be quite efficient and enough though.

Comment: @Rmano actually I don't know how `XeTeX` mechanism of inter-character classes would interact with a command issuing a `\special` containing `<<` and `>>`, as done by  `\PLS@AtBeginShipout`.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek  in `pdflscape.sty`, I see use of `\string<`, `\string>` in the `dvips` driver part but not in the `dvipdfm` part. It is clear that generally speaking a standard LaTeX package should not have to worry about `<, >` being active, but as `pdflscape.sty` takes precautions for `dvips` driver, perhaps it could do also for `dvipdfm` ?

Comment: @jfbu In `spanish` `<<>>` is unrelated to spacing.

Comment: @JavierBezos ok, hence possibly the somewhat thorny problems faced by Daniel when using `\XeTeXintercharclass` mechanism are not relevant to Spanish shorthands, and perhaps it would pay off using this mechanism in `spanish` rather than active characters.